Integral of $\tan(A+B)\tan(A-B)$
Evaluate $\int \tan(2x+a)\tan(2x-a) dx$
I actually got to this integral while trying to solve for the actual function $\frac{1}{\cos(2x+a)(\cos(2x-a))}$. I multiplied and divided by $\cos 2a=\cos((2x+a)-(2x-a))$ and then expanded the numerator thinking that it might be useful but it seems the problem is equally hard. Any suggestions on how to finish?

$\tan(2x+a)\tan(2x-a) = \frac{1}{2} \cot (2 a) (2 \tan (a+2 x)+2 \tan (a-2 x))-1$

@Basics thanks for the fast reply. Could you please share if there was any need for introducing the tan function? Or could we directly solve the original function?

Since $\int \tan x dx = - \ln|\cos x|$, you can do the integral.

https://www.integral-calculator.com/ gives a step-by-step solution.

$$\tan(2a)=\frac{\tan(2x+a)-\tan(2x-a)}{1+\tan(2x+a)\tan(2x-a)}$$
So $$\int \tan(2x+a)\tan(2x-a)\,dx=\int\left(\frac{\tan(2x+a)-\tan(2x-a)}{\tan(2a)}-1\right)\,dx\\=\frac{1}{2\tan(2a)}\ln\left(\frac{\cos(2x-a)}{\cos(2x+a)}\right)-x+C$$
